# Sort by certain data range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have table data like below. There are 4 columns: `DATE`, `SLIP_NO`, `ORDER_NO`, `ITEM_NAME`
・Data are being displayed in the order they were registered to the database, which records were registered first are displayed on top.
・There can be  multiple ORDER_NO values that are empty.

| DATE | SLIP_NO | ORDER_NO | ITEM_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-08-2023 | 006983 | J13828 | MIY-000-003 |
| 01-08-2023 | 006984 | J13830 | MIY-000-013 |
| 01-08-2023 | 006985 | J13829 | MIY-000-005 |
| 01-08-2023 | 076672 |  | MIY-000-010 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13838 | MIY-000-005 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13838 | MIY-000-005 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13840 | MIY-000-015 |
| 22-08-2023 | 006997 | J13855 | MIY-000-014 |
| 31-08-2023 | 000035 |  | TAX 10% |
| 31-08-2023 | 000034 |  | TAX 8% |

I want to sort them like this

| DATE | SLIP_NO | ORDER_NO | ITEM_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-08-2023 | 006983 | J13828 | MIY-000-003 |
| 01-08-2023 | 006984 | J13830 | MIY-000-013 |
| 01-08-2023 | 006985 | J13829 | MIY-000-005 |
| 01-08-2023 | 076672 |  | MIY-000-010 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13838 | MIY-000-005 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13838 | MIY-000-005 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13840 | MIY-000-015 |
| 22-08-2023 | 006997 | J13855 | MIY-000-014 |
| 31-08-2023 | 000034 |  | TAX 8% |
| 31-08-2023 | 000035 |  | TAX 10% |

The two lines `TAX 8%` and `TAX 10%` are always displayed at the bottom and it is the total amount of 8% or 10% tax of the items above it.

I would like to be able to change the display order of the two rows 8% and 10% without changing the order of the rows above 8% and 10%. Is this possible?
※I want to sort the last 2 rows based on the `ITEM_NAME` column and not based on the `SLIP_NO` column, because the value of column SLIP_NO(8%) can be smaller or larger than column SLIP_NO(10%)

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.DATE, C.SLIP_NO, C.ORDER_NO, C.ITEM_NAME
FROM BILL_PDF_TBL A 
    INNER JOIN BILL_TBL B ON A.PDF_ID = B.BILL_NO
    INNER JOIN BILL_DETAIL C ON B.BILL_NO = C.BILL_NO AND A.PDF_ID = C.BILL_NO
```

■■■Why not simply use ORDER BY date, slip_no? What's wrong with this?
＞Because the value of column SLIP_NO(8%) can be smaller or larger than colum SLIP_NO(10%). For example:

| DATE | SLIP_NO | ORDER_NO | ITEM_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-08-2023 | 000034 |  | TAX 10% |
| 31-08-2023 | 000035 |  | TAX 8% |

■■■How to sort the data if other rows with Tax 7%, Tax 16% etc. appear or if further Tax 8% rows appear having different values in the other columns?
＞ITEM_NAME that contains the word TAX is always inserted last so I only want to sort ITEM_NAME rows that contain the word TAX
without changing the order of ITEM_NAME rows that do not contain the word TAX of the items above it. For example:
**Before:**

| DATE | SLIP_NO | ORDER_NO | ITEM_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-08-2023 | 006983 | J13828 | MIY-000-003 |
| 01-08-2023 | 006984 | J13830 | MIY-000-013 |
| 01-08-2023 | 006985 | J13829 | MIY-000-005 |
| 01-08-2023 | 076672 |  | MIY-000-010 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13838 | MIY-000-005 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13838 | MIY-000-005 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13840 | MIY-000-015 |
| 22-08-2023 | 006997 | J13855 | MIY-000-014 |
| 31-08-2023 | 000034 |  | TAX 8% |
| 31-08-2023 | 000035 |  | TAX 16% |
| 31-08-2023 | 000037 |  | TAX 10% |
| 31-08-2023 | 000036 |  | TAX 7% |

**After:**

| DATE | SLIP_NO | ORDER_NO | ITEM_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-08-2023 | 006983 | J13828 | MIY-000-003 |
| 01-08-2023 | 006984 | J13830 | MIY-000-013 |
| 01-08-2023 | 006985 | J13829 | MIY-000-005 |
| 01-08-2023 | 076672 |  | MIY-000-010 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13838 | MIY-000-005 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13838 | MIY-000-005 |
| 08-08-2023 | 006986 | J13840 | MIY-000-015 |
| 22-08-2023 | 006997 | J13855 | MIY-000-014 |
| 31-08-2023 | 000036 |  | TAX 7% |
| 31-08-2023 | 000034 |  | TAX 8% |
| 31-08-2023 | 000037 |  | TAX 10% |
| 31-08-2023 | 000035 |  | TAX 16% |

■■■What to do if let's say a further row 15-09-2023,006999,J13860,MIY-000-018 exists? Should this row be sorted before or after the two "tax rows"?
＞This is 1 month's invoice data, so there is only August data, no other month data, and the tax rows will be calculated on the last day of the month then inserted last.

Comment: You asked this yesterday? What happened to that question?

Comment: @DaleK They removed it. @Natu Why not simply use `ORDER BY date, slip_no`? What's wrong with this? I guess you wrote the reason here: "the value of column SLIP_NO(8%) can be smaller or larger than colum SLIP_NO(10%)". But that's very vague, we can't work with that. Please add other possible use cases as sample data and add the expected result for those use cases.

Comment: One shouldn't delete a question, rather one should improve the existing question

Comment: How to sort the data if other rows with Tax 7%, Tax 16% etc. appear or if further Tax 8% rows appear having different values in the other columns?

Comment: @Natu one of the important things about this site is that you engage with people who interact with your question. So when people make comments requesting clarification, asking question etc, if you ignore them you're missing out on that assistance.

Comment: @Natu I forgot another use case: What to do if let's say a further row `15-09-2023,006999,J13860,MIY-000-018` exists? Should this row be sorted before or after the two "tax rows"? You would do much better to explain the target logic which should be applied for all possible use cases.

Comment: @JonasMetzler  Thank you for your questions to clarify the question. Sorry everyone because my question didn't provide enough information. m()m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all I read, it seems to me you want to apply following sort: First by date, then secondary by tax percentage if existing, and last by slip_no.

I think a good idea to cover this is to **create a tax table** which holds the possible taxes with their percentage. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE taxes (tax_name varchar(100), percentage int);
INSERT INTO taxes VALUES ('TAX 7%',7);
INSERT INTO taxes VALUES ('TAX 8%',8);
INSERT INTO taxes VALUES ('TAX 10%',10);
INSERT INTO taxes VALUES ('TAX 16%',16);
```

Then we can use a `LEFT JOIN` to the other table(s) and sort by the tax percentage:

```
SELECT 
  bd.date, bd.slip_no, bd.order_no, bd.item_name
FROM
  bill_detail bd LEFT JOIN taxes t
    ON bd.item_name = t.tax_name
ORDER BY bd.date, t.percentage, bd.slip_no;
```

(`bd.date` and `t.percentage` might be switched in the `ORDER BY` clause, but I guess, you want to sort by date first. Change it otherwise)

This query will produce the result you described, try out on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5Sn5LNEs) based on your sample data.

Note: Of course, you don't urgently need another table, you could use a substring function to fetch the percentage out of the item name and sort by it. But in my opinion, that's both bad readable and very unclean. It would maybe even be better to alter the original table by a tax percentage or tax id column and join with that column rather than the item name column. But I focused on answering your question, not rewriting your DB design.

If you are not allowed to create a new table, you can use a `CTE` instead:

```
WITH taxes AS
  (SELECT 'Tax 7%' AS tax_name, 7 AS percentage
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tax 8%', 8
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tax 10%', 10
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tax 16%', 16)
SELECT 
  bd.date, bd.slip_no, bd.order_no, bd.item_name
  FROM
    bill_detail bd LEFT JOIN taxes t
      ON bd.item_name = t.tax_name
ORDER BY bd.date, t.percentage, bd.slip_no;
```

The fiddle shows this creates the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your instructions, but I'm not allowed to create new tables...

Comment: Yes it's true I want to sort in order like that: `First by date, then secondary by tax percentage if existing, and last by slip_no`

Comment: @Natu In this case, you can use a `CTE`, I updated the answer.

Comment: with taxes as(
select item_name as tax_name,cast(replace(SUBSTRING(ITEM_NAME,5,4),'%','') as int) as percentage from sample where item_name like 'TAX%')

dynamically takes the percentage values

Comment: @Sam Yes, I wrote about that option in my answer, see "you could use a substring function to fetch the percentage out of the item name", but as said, I think this is bad style. Anyway, they can of course do so if they want. But if they want to do it this way, we will not need another table or a CTE, we would just directly put this in the `ORDER BY` clause.